# C# XDocument Saving is Not Being Updated Correctly

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML Document that I am inserting a new Element into.

I am using the following code:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(cust_file);

XElement parentXElement = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("LastLayout2/CommandBars");
XElement refXElement = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("LastLayout2/CommandBars/CommandBar[@Title = 'Standard']/Controls");

XElement temp = refXElement.XPathSelectElement("Control[@Parameter = 'GLOBAL!QMS_Launcher.Main']");

Console.WriteLine(refXElement);

XElement newElement = new XElement("Control");
XAttribute classAt = new XAttribute("Class", "CXTPControlButton");
                    XAttribute idAt = new XAttribute("Id", "0");
                    XAttribute paramAt = new XAttribute("Parameter", "GLOBAL!QMS_Launcher.Main");
XAttribute custIdAt = new XAttribute("CustomIconId", "68267");

XElement customIcon = new XElement("CustomIcon");
XElement icon = new XElement("Icon");
XAttribute width = new XAttribute("Width", "16");
XAttribute data = new XAttribute("Data", "ABAAAAAAFCAAAAAAEDAAICAAAAAAABAAAAAAABAAAAAABAAAACAADAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPPAAAAPPAAAAPPAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPGAAAAAAJNAAAAAAFCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANAAAAAAAHFAAAAAACHAAAAAAALAAAAAAPPAAAAAAJPAAAAAAHCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPFAAAAAAJOAAAAAAPPAAAAAAPPAAAAAAPPAAAAAALOABJAAACGDNJIAADNGJCGAAGJGAEAAAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGDAAAAAANPAAAAAAMPAAAAAAJLAAAAAAMHAAAAAAFFAAAAAAODAAAAAAAKMGFEAAEIPPGKAAPPPHDFAAPHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEMAAAAAAPPAAAAAAPGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANGAAAAAAPPCBMAAAIFIHOEAAIHJFJDAAJFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOOAAAAAAEPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPHAAAAAAPPGBOAAAKGILHHAAILILHHAAILJJEGAAJJFEMCAAFEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEPAAAAAAEOAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHJAAAAAAPPGCJBAAAHPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPMPEKAAMPPDJCAAPDAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOMAAAAAAPPAAAAAAJBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALLAAAAAAPPBCFBAAKFILHHAAILILHHAAILILHHAAILILHHAAILKGFEAAKGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANJAAAAAAPPAAAAAANMAAAAAABCAAAAAANBAAAAAABIAAAAAAPPAAAAAAHOAEKCAAMEIHOEAAIHIHOEAAIHIHOEAAIHIHOEAAIHJGDEAAJGGCJBAAGCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFBAAAAAADOAAAAAAPPAAAAAAPPAAAAAAPPAAAAAAPPAAAAAALPMAIAAAHGNOKJAANOPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPOPFKAAOPKFKDAAKFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKBAAAAAANJAAAAAABPAAAAAABPAAAAAAAMJBPAAALELMEIAALMPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPINMIAAINAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");

icon.Add(width, data);

customIcon.Add(icon);
newElement.Add(customIcon);

newElement.Add(classAt, idAt, paramAt, custIdAt);
refXElement.Add(newElement);

xDoc.Save(cust_file);
```

This does add the element to the XML file. However, the application that is reading the xml file does not seem to see the element when added via code. If I copy and paste the element manually, however, the application does see the new element. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong in my code.

Original XML

```
<LastLayout2 CompactMode="1" Schema="37">
    <CommandBars>
            <CommandBar Class="CXTPToolBar" BarID="200" Flags="63" Style="4194304" Title="Standard" MRUWidth="32767">
      <Controls>
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5864" Parameter="3000" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5866" Parameter="3001" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5868" Parameter="3002" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="24322" BeginGroup="1" Parameter="3003" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="24323" Parameter="3004" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="24324" Parameter="3005" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="24325" Parameter="3006" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="24321" BeginGroup="1" TooltipText="Undo" DescriptionText="Undo" Parameter="3007" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="24329" TooltipText="Redo" DescriptionText="Redo" Parameter="3008" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="6184" BeginGroup="1" Parameter="3009" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="6190" Parameter="3010" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="6148" Parameter="3011" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="6211" BeginGroup="1" Parameter="3012" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5796" BeginGroup="1" Parameter="3013" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5774" Parameter="3014" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5792" Parameter="3015" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5048" Parameter="3016" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5130" BeginGroup="1" Parameter="3017" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5936" Parameter="3018" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5844" Parameter="3019" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="6170" BeginGroup="1" Parameter="3020" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="6182" Parameter="3021" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="6384" BeginGroup="1" Parameter="3022" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="6385" Parameter="3023" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="6386" Parameter="3024" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="32769" BeginGroup="1" Parameter="3025" />
      </Controls>
    </CommandBar>
</CommandBars>
</LastLayout2>
```

Desired XML:

```
<LastLayout2 CompactMode="1" Schema="37">
    <CommandBars>
            <CommandBar Class="CXTPToolBar" BarID="200" Flags="63" Style="4194304" Title="Standard" MRUWidth="32767">
      <Controls>
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5864" Parameter="3000" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5866" Parameter="3001" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5868" Parameter="3002" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="24322" BeginGroup="1" Parameter="3003" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="24323" Parameter="3004" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="24324" Parameter="3005" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="24325" Parameter="3006" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="24321" BeginGroup="1" TooltipText="Undo" DescriptionText="Undo" Parameter="3007" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="24329" TooltipText="Redo" DescriptionText="Redo" Parameter="3008" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="6184" BeginGroup="1" Parameter="3009" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="6190" Parameter="3010" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="6148" Parameter="3011" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="6211" BeginGroup="1" Parameter="3012" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5796" BeginGroup="1" Parameter="3013" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5774" Parameter="3014" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5792" Parameter="3015" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5048" Parameter="3016" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5130" BeginGroup="1" Parameter="3017" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5936" Parameter="3018" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="5844" Parameter="3019" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="6170" BeginGroup="1" Parameter="3020" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="6182" Parameter="3021" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="6384" BeginGroup="1" Parameter="3022" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="6385" Parameter="3023" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="6386" Parameter="3024" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="32769" BeginGroup="1" Parameter="3025" />
        <Control Class="CXTPControlButton" Id="0" Parameter="GLOBAL!QMS_Launcher.Main" CustomIconId="68267">
            <CustomIcon>
                <Icon Width="16" Data="ABAAAAAAFCAAAAAAEDAAICAAAAAAABAAAAAAABAAAAAABAAAACAADAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPPAAAAPPAAAAPPAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPGAAAAAAJNAAAAAAFCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANAAAAAAAHFAAAAAACHAAAAAAALAAAAAAPPAAAAAAJPAAAAAAHCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPFAAAAAAJOAAAAAAPPAAAAAAPPAAAAAAPPAAAAAALOABJAAACGDNJIAADNGJCGAAGJGAEAAAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGDAAAAAANPAAAAAAMPAAAAAAJLAAAAAAMHAAAAAAFFAAAAAAODAAAAAAAKMGFEAAEIPPGKAAPPPHDFAAPHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEMAAAAAAPPAAAAAAPGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANGAAAAAAPPCBMAAAIFIHOEAAIHJFJDAAJFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOOAAAAAAEPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPHAAAAAAPPGBOAAAKGILHHAAILILHHAAILJJEGAAJJFEMCAAFEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEPAAAAAAEOAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHJAAAAAAPPGCJBAAAHPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPMPEKAAMPPDJCAAPDAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOMAAAAAAPPAAAAAAJBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALLAAAAAAPPBCFBAAKFILHHAAILILHHAAILILHHAAILILHHAAILKGFEAAKGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANJAAAAAAPPAAAAAANMAAAAAABCAAAAAANBAAAAAABIAAAAAAPPAAAAAAHOAEKCAAMEIHOEAAIHIHOEAAIHIHOEAAIHIHOEAAIHJGDEAAJGGCJBAAGCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFBAAAAAADOAAAAAAPPAAAAAAPPAAAAAAPPAAAAAAPPAAAAAALPMAIAAAHGNOKJAANOPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPOPFKAAOPKFKDAAKFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKBAAAAAANJAAAAAABPAAAAAABPAAAAAAAMJBPAAALELMEIAALMPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPPPGKAAPPINMIAAINAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" />
             </CustomIcon>
         </Control>
      </Controls>
    </CommandBar>
</CommandBars>
</LastLayout2>
```

Comment: Most likely you are not setting XML namespaces properly, but it is not possible to say for sure without seeing actual and expected XML output.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I added the XML. The original does not have an <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> at the top. But when I run my code, it does. Maybe this is what is causing the problem?

Comment: Should not... Thanks for update - Hopefully someone will try your code to see diffs.

Comment: First: your XML samples does not valid, as closing tags does not match. Second: if correct closing tags, then your code correctly make desired XML from original XML, at least `XNode.DeepEquals` say so.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks for that, the actual XML's have the </CommandBar> tag. I must have accidentally deleted it when I was reducing the XML length. Was that the tag you were mentioning that was missing?

Comment: Not only that. You have two `<LastLayout2>` tags but no `</LastLayout2>` tag. Main problem here is that your XML samples does not allow to reproduce the problem. Your code correctly transform original XML to desired XML.

Comment: @PetSerAl Sorry, I must have mistyped when editing the xml. The original xml is too long to post here.